# Qt: How to handle forms?

Tags: qt, forms

I'm creating an application in Qt (Nokia SDK) which should hold a login screen, main menu screen, etc....
But what is the best way to jump back and forward on these screens?

I have recently looked at Stacked Widget, and it seems like that could solve my case, but it has some kind of margin on itself, that makes it look weird. (Makes the widget not fill the entire screen)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QStackedWidget doesn't have any margins. You should check if you are using layouts with margins. Usually you will have layout for each page of stacked widget.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a layout, select it and in properties, set margin values to 0

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have not done much on that widget, so i just copied some elements and started over by creating the QStackedWidget first. That worked.